# Does proving that a property holds for every set with $n$ elements implies it holds positive integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, induction

If we prove by using PMI that some predicate $P(\mathbf{X})$ is true for every set $\mathbf{X}$ with $n$ elements, for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, can we say that $P(\mathbf{X})$ holds for $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$? Or are we limited to ensure it is true only if $\mathbf{X}$ is finite?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let $P$ be the property that for any finite set $S$ there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $N >|x|$ for all $x\in S$.

Comment: Good example, $P(\mathbb{N})$ is false because there is no upper bound for $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if it's finite!

To see this in the quickest way possible, let $P(X)$ be the property "X is a finite set"!

For a more substantive example, let $P(X)$ be the property, "$\sum_{x\in X}\frac{1}{x}$ is convergent." Or, "$\sum_{x\in X}\frac{(-1)^x}{x}$ is a rational number."

Comment: Why use an alternating series? (Just out of curiosity)

Comment: Otherwise the limit is not irrational but just doesn't exist.

Comment: @AdamHughes - I wanted an example where $P$ was not just a statement that something is finite. The alternating series converges even for infinite $X$, so I could have $P$ be a more interesting statement about the limit and not just that a limit exists.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith right, but one could for example choose $X = \{2n+1 : n\in\Bbb N\}$ and it would still diverge with alternating just as one could choose $X = \{2^n : n\in\Bbb N\}$ and get convergence (even to a rational number!) even when the series is not alternating. I thought you might have had a deep reason why that was a particularly illuminating case over the simpler one, since the limit does not necessarily exist even in the alternating case.

Comment: @user39082 But that doesn't change based on infinite or not. See my above examples.

Comment: @AdamHughes - I wasn't looking for examples where the property precisely distinguished finite from infinite $X$. I was just looking for counterexamples to the hypothesis in the OP - that proving $P$ for all finite $X$ implied it for $X=\mathbb{Z}^{>0}$. The first example ("$X$ is finite") does the trick, but I thought it might be unsatisfying to the OP since the failure of the property in the case $X=\mathbb{Z}^{>0}$ is totally tautological. The second example $\sum_{x\in X} 1/x$ was designed to have more substance, but I thought it *still* might not be satisfying because (cont'd...)

Comment: it's still a finiteness claim. So the idea of the third example was to give something where the property $P$ wasn't explicitly about finiteness, as though to say, "other types of mathematical property (than finiteness) can also be true for every finite set of naturals and still fail for $\mathbb{Z}^{>0}$." I hoped this would make the danger of carrying a result from the finite to the infinite case feel substantive.

Comment: @AdamHughes aside: I don't know if what you wrote is exactly what you meant but it's not quite right. The alternating sum over reciprocals of the odds does not diverge. In fact, an alternating sum over reciprocals of an increasing sequence of natural numbers will *always* converge, or more generally any alternating series of positive real numbers whose magnitudes tend to zero, because the interval between any two consecutive partial sums bounds all subsequent partial sums and its length gets arbitrarily small. (The alternating sum of the odds comes out to $\pi/4$, look up "Leibniz series.")

Comment: But as you are suggesting, it is possible to choose a subset of the natural numbers so that the alternating sum of its reciprocals is rational (e.g. take $X= \{2^n\}$), so rationality vs. irrationality of $\sum_{x\in X}(-1)^x/x$ is not a test of whether $X$ is infinite. I only brought it up as something that isn't a finiteness claim but where the truth for finite $X$ does not imply the truth for infinite $X$.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith you wrote $(-1)^x$ which means when $x=2n+1$ it's *always* -1, i.e. it no longer alternates. If you want to get it to, you'll need to say something like index your x, and that's not canonical, since you'd not be guaranteed it alternated for every enumeration of $\Bbb N$, you see how this gets rather messy.

Comment: @AdamHughes - you're right of course. I hope I've spoken to your question about why I went with the alternating series in the first place, which this is tangential to.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Yes you have, I can see the motivation much more clearly now. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting but important one:

> Let $P(X)$ be that every injection from $X$ to $X$ is also a surjection.
>
> Then $P(X)$ for every finite set $X$, but $P(\mathbb{N})$ is clearly false.

This property $P$ is used in many proofs, such as that the Frobenius map $( x \mapsto x^p )$ is surjective on any finite field of characteristic $p$.

Answer (score 2):

> Every finite (non-empty) partial order has a maximal element.

We prove this by induction. Suppose that $A$ is given with a partial order. If $A$ is a singleton, we're done. If not, pick some $a\in A$ and consider $A'=A\setminus\{a\}$ with the restriction of the partial order to $A'$ (note that $A'$ is non-empty). By the induction hypothesis $A'$ has a maximal element $b$. If $b\nleq a$, then $b$ is a maximal element in $A$, otherwise $a$ is a maximal element.$\qquad\square$

Clearly, however, this does not hold for $\Bbb Z^+$, as there are many partial orders on the natural numbers without a maximal element. I will leave it to you as an exercise to come up with one.